# How to set the CPropertyPage title in Wizard mode

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to set the title of a CPropertyPage dynamically in a MFC form. This form created with wizard mode. Here is my code. This code compile and run doesn't set the title. How can I set the title of wizard windows?

```
BOOL MyForm::OnSetActive()
{
    CPropertySheet* pWnd = (CPropertySheet*) GetParent();
    pWnd->SetTitle(L"My Title",PSH_PROPTITLE);  
    return CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
}
```

Comment: you normally create the page with the title and sub-title attached to them, e.g. your MyForm would have been created like this: MyForm *pForm = CMyPropertyPage(idTemplate, idCaption, idHeaderTitle, idHeaderSubTitle). See the Constructor of property page here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y9a2ksw2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to set the title of the property page or the property sheet? Your question is for the page, the code tries it for the sheet.

Comment: @cha/dwo - I need to change the title of wizard window. If I add this code under a button click event, It works fine. I think title change overwriting by the default title again if I call this in `OnSetAvtive()` but even I tried this change put in to `OnInitDialog()` and  `DoDataExchange()` also. but couldn't make it work. Any idea to avoid overwriting by default title after set this or which dialog event I have to use? Thank you

Comment: do not call return CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();. Or if you you want to call the base classes method, call it as a first statement, like this: int iRet = CPropertyPage::OnSetActive(); /// do some other stuff ///; return iRet;

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it on event WM_SHOWWINDOW. In my code it works like:

```
void CPropSIni::OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus)
{
    CPropertyPage::OnShowWindow(bShow, nStatus);

    CNodeSheet* pSheet = (CNodeSheet*)GetParent();
    if ( (bShow==TRUE) && (pSheet->IsWizard()) )
    {   
        CString strTemp;
        pSheet->GetWindowText(strTemp);     

        CString strCaption;
        strCaption = CustomFormat(CART_CAPTION_FORMAT_ADD, 2, strTemp, pSheet->m_Name);

        CPropertyPage::OnSetActive();
        pSheet->SetTitle(strCaption);
    }
}
```